# Looping php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Am requesting 4 help in putting such an array in a loop;

```
$name_array = array(

array('Name1','Title1','website1'),
array('Name2','Title2','website2'),
array('Name3','Title3','website3'),
);
```

I thought a simple loop as this would but returns a syntax error;

```
  $name_array = array(

for($p=0;$p<=3;$p++){
       array('$name[$p]','$title[$p]','$website[p]'),
    }
);
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: what do you want to obtain at the end?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? This looks like random code. I mean, the first snippet fills an array with data. How would you do that in a loop? The data has to come from somewhere.

Comment: '$website[$p]' seems more consistent, may want to drop the quotes

Comment: In the mean time, 6 wild guesses about what one could mean with this code.

Comment: Am sori not being detailed but for the second code am extracting the same data from the database. Just wanted 2 know the looping... thx sofar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name_array = array();
for ($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
  $name_array[] = array('Name' . $x, 'Title' . $x, 'website' . $x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leonard, that's perfect. Multi-dimensional was the way out, mob thx.

Answer (score 2):

you are combining multiple things in this line,

```
$name_array = array(
for($p=0;$p<=3;$p++){
   array('$name[$p]','$title[$p]','$website[p]'),
}
);
```

1. `=` is an assignment operator, assigns right-hand side value to left-hand side variable. eg. `$name_array = array();`
2. you should not have an array surrounding a `for` loop
3. `array('$name[$p]','$title[$p]','$website[p]')` ..the variables `$name[$p], $title[$p] and $website[$p]` shouldn't be enclosed in quotes.

what you need is this,

```
for($p=0;$p<=3;$p++){
   $name_array[] = array('Name'.$p,'Title'.$p,'Website'.$p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$name_array=array();
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $name_array[]=array('Name'.$i, 'Title'.$i, 'Website'.$i);
}
```

So as you can see, there were quite a few errors in your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have arrays `$name`, `$title`, and `$website` and they're all the same length:

```
$name_array = array();
for($x = 0; $x < count($name); $x++) {
   $name_array[] = array($name[$x], $title[$x], $website[$x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like

```
for($p=0;$p<=3;$p++){ /you can use the count to like count($name_array)
       $name[$p] =$p;

 //or echo 

      echo $name[$p];
    }
```